# Run-time error "'-2147417848 (80010108)': Automation error, The object Invoked has disconnect from its clients" when running excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

A few colleagues are getting the above error when running a macro, while the majority on my team using the same macro are not getting the issue. We're all on the same version of excel, 2307 (Build 16626.20170). Other macros are working for them, we've tried re-installing excel - nothing has worked so far. It seems like it is the two bolded lines at the bottom here that is giving the error:

```
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AN-Type"
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],"" ("",RC[2],"")"")"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    **Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False**
```

Could there be some setting in their excel install that would trigger the error on their machines, while others using the same exact macro would be using it with no issues?

The macro adds a number of tabs, filters data and moves it to the appropriate tab, and does a number of formatting steps.

Comment: Side note: You're writing that formula all the way to the very last row in column D... do you need that? Also a side note, but consider rewriting to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: `Selection.Value = Selection.Value` would be better than copy/pastevalues

Answer (score 0):

The code could be simplified as below.

```vb
    Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    With Rows("1:1").Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Style = "Comma"
    Range("B1").Value = "AN-Type"
    Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Dim rngD As Range
    Set rngD = Range("D2:D" & ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row)
    rngD.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],"" ("",RC[2],"")"")"
    rngD.Formula = rngD.Value
```